# Krunker Editor player falling after spawning

Tags: krunker-editor

I've built an amazing map which just includes a single stone cube as a platform:

[image: Cube Platform Map]

However, when you spawn in, you just seem to be floating in space.

[image: Void Image on Spawn]

I want the players to be on my stone platform when they spawn.  Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Spawn Point.  This allows you to specify where the players will be spawned at.  It also allows for more complex integration such as saying which team spawns at which spawn point.  The option for creating a new spawn point is `Object > Zones > Spawn Point` which can be accessed from the top menu.

[image: Spawn Point Setting Location]

After you have created a spawn point, you can change the direction the player would look at via the `direction` property and move it around to choose where the player would spawn at.  The purple arrow indicates which direction the player will be facing when they spawn.  I will just leave the settings as default and place it directly in the center of your platform.  I also placed it a little above the ground to avoid the player glitching through the floor.

[image: Spawn Point Demo]

After that, you should see the player spawns correctly on your awsome stone platform after you spawn in by testing via sandbox mode:

[image: Player Demo]